# Chinese Idiom puzzle 7

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. To win a war, you need XX, YY, and 人和, What are XX and YY?
2. All formed by nature, no traces of man-made carvings
3. One hand covers the sky. ( Describes someone use his power to deceive the masses)
4. Far away; the edge of the world
5. Describe 'very happy'
6. A metaphor of extremely strict preventive measures  (intruder will not escape)
7. Steal the Sky, switch the sun. A metaphor for pulling off a great deception
8. Heaven's proud son (Metaphor of talented and influential people)
9. Unrealistic and unreasonable strange ideas
10. Vivid like sky raining flowers. Mostly refer to exaggerated and unrealistic speech
11. Live as long as heaven
12. Man can overcome nature (with determination and diligent)
13. Create a new world
14. Common people care the most is food. 《漢書．卷四三．酈食其傳》
15. Heaven's will
16. Genius
17. Under the sky (the whole world)
18. Vast space
19. Violate Heaven's rule
20. Nickname of 包拯
21. A metaphor of an extremely beautiful woman
22. Two people are each at a different corner of the world. Describes that they are far apart and difficult to meet. 出自《古诗四首》

A. Reach the sky in one step. A metaphor to reach a high level or degree at once. Sometimes it is also used to metaphor a person's sudden ambition and climb to a high position. 出自《清稗类钞·三十四》

B. Heaven's fairy change into human (describe beauty)

C. The ocean and the sky are the same color

D. Engulf heaven and earth

E. World turns dark

F. Weather is hard to predict

G. Heaven's horse runs in the sky (metaphor of creative and unrestrained imagination)

H. If the emperor break the law, he is subjected to the same punishment as a common citizen would

I. completely fair and reasonable

J. Ancient Chinese believed the shapes of the sky and the earth are ...?

K. 盤 __ created the sky

L. The South Gate of the Heavenly court (天庭)

M. Nickname of Sichuan (四川) area

N. Indulging in wine and women

O. There is only one sun in the sky (下一句是"民無二主")

P. Peace on earth

More hints below

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

> [image]

green: I need the spoiler
red: I am not sure

Comment: Good job! (2) is "渾X天X"  ( 21) is "天香國色 "( D) is "鋪天X地", The others are all correct

Comment: that's interesting! what is 15? @Tang Ho

Comment: My answer for 15. is 天意, but 天命 seems correct too, BTW, why the green text?

Comment: Green meant I have to see the spoiler hint; this is interesting @Tang Ho

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  1, 天時，地利
>  2，渾然天成
>  3，隻手遮天
>  4，天涯海角
>  5，歡天喜地
>  6，天羅地網
>  7，偷天換日
>  8，天之驕子
>  9，異想天開
>  10，天花亂墜
>  11，壽與天齊
>  12，人定勝天
>  13，開天闢地
>  14，民以食為天
>  15，天意
>  16，天才
>  17，普天之下
>  18，海闊天空
>  19，罪犯天條
>  20，包青天
>  21，天香國色
>  22，天各一方
>  A,一步登天
>  B,天仙佳人
>  C,海天一色
>  D,鋪天蓋地
>  E,天昏地暗
>  F，天有不測之風雲
>  G, 天馬行空
>  H，天子犯法與庶民同罪
>  I, 天公地義
>  J，天圓地方，
>  K，盤古開天
>  L，南天門
>  M，天府之國
>  N，花天酒地
>  O，天無二日
>  P，天下太平
> ```

Comment: Great job! Two mistakes (B,) Heaven's fairy **change** into human = 天仙 **化**人, But 天仙佳人 is close enough; (I)  is 天公地道. You wrote 天公地義. Since there's another idiom 天經地義, I would count your answer for (I) acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

> [image]

1. To win a war, you need XX, YY, and 人和, What are XX and YY?
2. All formed by nature, no traces of man-made carvings
3. One hand covers the sky. ( Describes someone use his power to deceive the masses)
4. Far away; the edge of the world
5. Describe 'very happy'
6. A metaphor of extremely strict preventive measures  (intruder will not escape)
7. Steal the Sky, switch the sun. A metaphor for pulling off a great deception
8. Heaven's proud son (Metaphor of talented and influential people)
9. Unrealistic and unreasonable strange ideas
10. Vivid like sky raining flowers. Mostly refer to exaggerated and unrealistic speech
11. Live as long as heaven
12. Man can overcome nature (with determination and diligent)
13. Create a new world
14. Common people care the most is food. 《漢書．卷四三．酈食其傳》
15. Heaven's will
16. Genius
17. Under the sky (the whole world)
18. Vast space
19. Violate Heaven's rule
20. Nickname of 包拯
21. A metaphor of an extremely beautiful woman
22. Two people are each at a different corner of the world. Describes that they are far apart and difficult to meet. 出自《古诗四首》

A. Reach the sky in one step. A metaphor to reach a high level or degree at once. Sometimes it is also used to metaphor a person's sudden ambition and climb to a high position. 出自《清稗类钞·三十四》

B. Heaven's fairy change into human (describe beauty)

C. The ocean and the sky are the same color

D. Engulf heaven and earth

E. World turns dark

F. Weather is hard to predict

G. Heaven's horse runs in the sky (metaphor of creative and unrestrained imagination)

H. If the emperor break the law, he is subjected to the same punishment as a common citizen would

I. completely fair and reasonable

J. Ancient Chinese believed the shapes of the sky and the earth are ...?

K. 盤 __ created the sky

L. The South Gate of the Heavenly court (天庭)

M. Nickname of Sichuan (四川) area

N. Indulging in wine and women

O. There is only one sun in the sky (下一句是"民無二主")

P. Peace on earth